# Reputation on Meta site

Tags: bug, reputation, meta

I can see that Meta reputation for each user is separate from Beta.

Many users on Meta only have 101 reputation points even though they are actively commenting and answering questions (and so I assume voting) on the Meta questions. This was the case for me, even though I had answers on Meta that were upvoted and even accepted.

**EDIT:**
However, once I ASKED a question on Meta, then my reputation jumped substantially. Is that normal behavior on Meta (asking a question is required to start reputation activity), or is that a bug?

Comment: Well...as soon as I asked a question mine went up...so I will edit my question!

Comment: Most of your questions should be covered by [this help center article](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Yes that helps with knowing votes etc don’t matter on meta, but it says the rep points should be syncing every hour and that is definitely not the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta does not affect your reputation on any site except [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). So if you post and get a post score of `-9999` you will lose 0 rep.

Your rep on meta is the same on the main site but it only refreshes every hour (I think).

Comment: Thanks, Ethan, that makes sense. It seems like it does not refresh to mirror your reputation on the main site until you've actually asked a question on Meta.

Comment: It's not refreshing every hour.